# How to keep classes which can be obfuscated

Tags: android, proguard, android-instant-apps

**How can I keep classes which can be obfuscated?**

I played with `-keep` and `-keepclassmembers`, both will fix my class not found exceptions, but I would like to have shorted names. 
As background, I need that for a *instant app*: That means that I need to define myself which classes should been kept in the base module for the feature modules. In the end I have now a list of **3k classes**, but *I'm not interested in the full class names and the member variables*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following modifier with -keep rules:

```
-keep,allowobfuscation class xxx { yyy; }
```

This will prevent these classes/methods from being shrunk and optimized but they can be obfuscated. Take a look at the [manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#keepoptionmodifiers) which describes the various modifiers.